# Libsvm java training testing example(also in real time)

Tags: java, machine-learning, computer-vision, libsvm

Anybody can help me by providing libsvm java example for training and testing. I am new in Machine learning and need help regarding the same. Earlier provided example by @machine learner have error giving only one class result. I don't want to use weka as suggestion given in earlier post.

Or can you rectify error in this code it always predict one class in result.(I want to perform multiclassification). 
This example is given by "Machine learner"

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import libsvm.*;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        // Preparing the SVM param
        svm_parameter param=new svm_parameter();
        param.svm_type=svm_parameter.C_SVC;
        param.kernel_type=svm_parameter.RBF;
        param.gamma=0.5;
        param.nu=0.5;
        param.cache_size=20000;
        param.C=1;
        param.eps=0.001;
        param.p=0.1;

        HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Double>> featuresTraining=new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Double>>();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> labelTraining=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Double>> featuresTesting=new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Double>>();

        HashSet<Integer> features=new HashSet<Integer>();

        //Read in training data
        BufferedReader reader=null;
        try{
            reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a1a.train"));
            String line=null;
            int lineNum=0;
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                featuresTraining.put(lineNum, new HashMap<Integer,Double>());
                String[] tokens=line.split("\\s+");
                int label=Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
                labelTraining.put(lineNum, label);
                for(int i=1;i<tokens.length;i++){
                    String[] fields=tokens[i].split(":");
                    int featureId=Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
                    double featureValue=Double.parseDouble(fields[1]);
                    features.add(featureId);
                    featuresTraining.get(lineNum).put(featureId, featureValue);
                }
            lineNum++;
            }

            reader.close();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

        //Read in test data
        try{
            reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a1a.t"));
            String line=null;
            int lineNum=0;
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){

                featuresTesting.put(lineNum, new HashMap<Integer,Double>());
                String[] tokens=line.split("\\s+");
                for(int i=1; i<tokens.length;i++){
                    String[] fields=tokens[i].split(":");
                    int featureId=Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
                    double featureValue=Double.parseDouble(fields[1]);
                    featuresTesting.get(lineNum).put(featureId, featureValue);
                }
            lineNum++;
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

        //Train the SVM model
        svm_problem prob=new svm_problem();
        int numTrainingInstances=featuresTraining.keySet().size();
        prob.l=numTrainingInstances;
        prob.y=new double[prob.l];
        prob.x=new svm_node[prob.l][];

        for(int i=0;i<numTrainingInstances;i++){
            HashMap<Integer,Double> tmp=featuresTraining.get(i);
            prob.x[i]=new svm_node[tmp.keySet().size()];
            int indx=0;
            for(Integer id:tmp.keySet()){
                svm_node node=new svm_node();
                node.index=id;
                node.value=tmp.get(id);
                prob.x[i][indx]=node;
                indx++;
            }

            prob.y[i]=labelTraining.get(i);
        }

        svm_model model=svm.svm_train(prob,param);

        for(Integer testInstance:featuresTesting.keySet()){
            HashMap<Integer, Double> tmp=new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
            int numFeatures=tmp.keySet().size();
            svm_node[] x=new svm_node[numFeatures];
            int featureIndx=0;
            for(Integer feature:tmp.keySet()){
                x[featureIndx]=new svm_node();
                x[featureIndx].index=feature;
                x[featureIndx].value=tmp.get(feature);
                featureIndx++;
            }

            double d=svm.svm_predict(model, x);

            System.out.println(testInstance+"\t"+d);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a short, self contained example that illustrates your problem (http://sscce.org/). You will need to post a minimal java, and a1a.train and a1a.t that illustrate your problem. It seems like you think you're doing everything perfectly and LIBSVM is just broken. I assure you that is not the case.

Comment: I know there is nothing wrong with libsvm .The way i am using that is wrong.I thing error in way I am reading the test file"a1a.t".If you rectify in above code it will be helpful for me.

Comment: Now I am able to perform classification but now how to get confidence value of each class.(in java)

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

It is because your featuresTesting is never used, `HashMap<Integer, Double> tmp=new HashMap<Integer, Double>();` should be `HashMap<Integer, Double> tmp=featuresTesting.get(testInstance);`

Answer (score 2):

you could use javaML library to classify your data

it is a sample code with javaML:

```
   Classifier clas = new LibSVM();
        clas.buildClassifier(data);
        Dataset dataForClassification= FileHandler.loadDataset(new File(.),            0, ",");
        /* Counters for correct and wrong predictions. */
        int correct = 0, wrong = 0;
        /* Classify all instances and check with the correct class values */
        for (Instance inst : dataForClassification) {
            Object predictedClassValue = clas.classify(inst);
            Map<Object,Double> map = clas.classDistribution(inst);
            Object realClassValue = inst.classValue();
            if (predictedClassValue.equals(realClassValue))
                correct++;
            else
                wrong++;
        }
```

Comment: Here I am not getting how to perform training if I have feature vector file in Libsvm format.Can you please give some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're having trouble understanding what you're doing, and are just copying code from here and there. It may help you to understand basic machine learning. For example you should probably read this [practical guide for SVM classification](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) from the authors of LIBSVM (the library you use). The advice you got here that you should probably take an introductory machine learning course online is probably even better.

Let me also give you two big tips, that may save you time if you're getting all results of the same class:

1. Are you normalizing your data, making all values lie between 0 and 1
   (or between -1 and 1), either linearly or using the mean and the
   standard deviation? It doesn't seem from your code like you are.
2. Are you parameter searching for a good value of C (or C and gamma in
   the case of an RBF kernel)? Doing cross validation or on a hold out
   set? It doesn't seem fro your code that you are.

Comment: I had checked accuracy of my dataset from command line using libsvm and its giving good result without scaling.Scaling I had done at the time of feature extraction only,Now I want to embed libsvm in my project.I have training and testing file in libsvm format.Now how to do program using libsvm in java that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A) No one knows that you are referencing. Give links if you wan't people to understand what you are referring to.

B) You need to take a course on Machine Learning. There is a free one on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml). The output of a model is dependent upon the data itself - and heavily influenced by the model parameters. The model parameters are effected by scaling, and you generally need to do a search for them. Your code incorporates none of this - and you have made it clear you are new to Machine Learning. You will waists hours and days and weeks on what could be done in a few minutes by obtaining the necessary background knowledge.

C) There are numerous version of LIBSVM for Java, and you have provided no indication of which one you are using. Each one works somewhat differently.

Comment: I am using libsvm 3.17.and reference which I mention have same code which I put.